# Find kernel of a linear transformation if it possible.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

[image: Task]

My approach to this task is to find a matrix $M_{S}(F)$ where $S= \{(3,2,2),(1,2,1),(2,3,2)\}.$

But I have also thought that is keep staying in my mind that we are not really given a basis so it might be impossible to find a kernel as it is not said if there are no other elements for (example $(a,b,c)$ for which $F(a,b,c) = (c,d,e)$ etc.).

So is it possible to find a $\operatorname{kernel}(F)$ or not hmm?

Comment: S=$\{(3,2,2),(1,2,1),(2,3,3)\}$ is a basis has it is linearly independent and $Dim(S)=3$ so the linear transformation is defined on a basis

Comment: But is it stated in this task that S is actually a basis? Can't it be only a set of a few elements from it?

Comment: It is not stated, but you can prove/check it easily

Comment: Note proper MathJax usage, as in my edits to this question.

Comment: @gbox : Standard notation is $\dim(S),$ not $dim(S)$ or $Dim(S). \qquad$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem here is to check whether $F$ is well-defined in the first place.

Normally, if a linear function (in particular a linear operator) is defined on a basis, it uniquely gets extended to the whole domain. In our case, it is defined on the vectors $(3,2,2), (1,2,1), (2,3,2)$, so all it takes is to check if those vectors form a basis. Depending on what you know about vector spaces, there are different ways of doing that: one possible way is to turn those vectors into columns and check if the matrix that you obtain, i.e. $\begin{bmatrix}3&1&2\\2&2&3\\2&1&2\end{bmatrix}$, is non-singular (i.e. has a nonzero determinant). Indeed, its determinant is $1$, which proves that $(3,2,2), (1,2,1), (2,3,2)$ is a basis.

Now we know $F$ is a well-defined linear operator, you can proceed to find its kernel.

Comment: So we would not be able to find a kernel(F) if we would get that $S$ is not a basis right?

Comment: @JamesSmith Worse, we would not know what $F$ is in the first place. If your given set is not linearly independent, then there is a possibility that there is no such $F$. (E.g. $v_3=v_1+v_2$ but $F(v_3)\ne F(v_1)+F(v_2)$.) If the set is not spanning the whole domain, then $F$ would be ambiguous (if it exists, subject to my previous sentence) and so would be its kernel.

Comment: Mhm, that's right. So when we can't find a kernel(F)? I have never met such an example.

Comment: Then you would, as it says in the statement of the problem, explain why, and you would then point out that $F$ is not well defined because the given set is not linearly independent, or because it does not span the whole space.

Comment: Mhm, thanks. So the moment when we can't find a kernel(F) is when we can't define F properly? Or might there be an other factor that may lead to inability to find a kernel(F)?

Comment: @JamesSmith No, that is all. Every linear function (in particular linear operator) has a kernel.

Comment: Okey. Thanks a lot.